# custom location of aop.xml

Tags: aspectj

There is a system property to provide custom location for aspectJ aop.xml configuration.

-D org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=META-INF/myaop.xml

Can I provide this location as an absolute location somewhere outside of the application WAR? It didn't work when I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the sources of AspectJ 1.7.1, it appears you can provide a file URL to your aop.xml. Possibly works in earlier versions as well, I haven't checked.

So something like -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.configuration=file://path/to/aop.xml should work.